# ReportLab Image Link

Tags: python, reportlab

Is there a way to add an href/link to a Platypus Image object in ReportLab? I know how to add a link on text in a Paragraph but I can't seem to find anything about adding a link for an Image.

Comment: For future explorers here: it's also possible inside a Paragraph `<link>` to put an `<img>`. But perils await. It's `valign` not `align` unlike HTML. It's `valign=baseline` not `valign=bottom` contrary to the [docs](https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/). Then mysteriously the link may not work at all unless you add plain text inside or between the links. Try underscore. I know right.

Answer (score 6):

This can be easily achieved with the [HyperlinkedImage class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114820/is-it-possible-to-get-a-flowables-coordinate-position-once-its-rendered-using) proposed by missmely:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image

class HyperlinkedImage(Image, object):

    # The only variable I added to __init__() is hyperlink. I default it to None for the if statement I use later.
    def __init__(self, filename, hyperlink=None, width=None, height=None, kind='direct', mask='auto', lazy=1):
        super(HyperlinkedImage, self).__init__(filename, width, height, kind, mask, lazy)
        self.hyperlink = hyperlink

    def drawOn(self, canvas, x, y, _sW=0):
        if self.hyperlink: # If a hyperlink is given, create a canvas.linkURL()
            x1 = self.hAlignAdjust(x, _sW) # This is basically adjusting the x coordinate according to the alignment given to the flowable (RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER)
            y1 = y
            x2 = x1 + self._width
            y2 = y1 + self._height
            canvas.linkURL(url=self.hyperlink, rect=(x1, y1, x2, y2), thickness=0, relative=1)
        super(HyperlinkedImage, self).drawOn(canvas, x, y, _sW)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small update to make @Meilo's great answer work with reportlab 3.3.0. It fixes `_hAlignAdjust` method name and adds `hAlign` kwarg:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image

class HyperlinkedImage(Image, object):
    """Image with a hyperlink, adopted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26294527/304209."""

    def __init__(self, filename, hyperlink=None, width=None, height=None, kind='direct',
                 mask='auto', lazy=1, hAlign='CENTER'):
        """The only variable added to __init__() is hyperlink.

        It defaults to None for the if statement used later.
        """
        super(HyperlinkedImage, self).__init__(filename, width, height, kind, mask, lazy,
                                               hAlign=hAlign)
        self.hyperlink = hyperlink

    def drawOn(self, canvas, x, y, _sW=0):
        if self.hyperlink:  # If a hyperlink is given, create a canvas.linkURL()
            # This is basically adjusting the x coordinate according to the alignment
            # given to the flowable (RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER)
            x1 = self._hAlignAdjust(x, _sW)
            y1 = y
            x2 = x1 + self._width
            y2 = y1 + self._height
            canvas.linkURL(url=self.hyperlink, rect=(x1, y1, x2, y2), thickness=0, relative=1)
        super(HyperlinkedImage, self).drawOn(canvas, x, y, _sW)
```